# Modulo with primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We used the following statement in a proof in my algebra class, but I can't see an easy way to proof this statement:

Let $p,q$ be prime numbers with $p>q$,
$k \in \{0,...,p-1\}$, s.t. $k^q = 1$ mod $p$.
Now let $n>1$ be the smallest natural number, s.t. $n^q = 1$ mod $p$.
It follows, that $n = k^s$ mod $p$ with $s \in \{1, ..., q-1\}$.

It is obvious, that $n^q = k^q$ mod $p$, but what is the idea for a proof of $n = k^s$ mod $p$ with $s \in \{1, ..., q-1\}$?

Comment: It isn't true.  You could have $k=1$, for example.

Comment: If you exclude $k\equiv 1 \pmod p$ then it follows since the integers $\pmod p$ are a field.  There are exactly $q$ roots of $x^q\equiv 1 \pmod q$, and these are given by the powers of $k$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it, but did you mean $x^q ≡ 1$ (mod $p$)?

Comment: Absolutely, yes.  Sorry for the typo.